# Current user id is persistent after signing out | Firebase Auth | Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

**AuthService.dart**

```
 static Future<void> login(
      BuildContext context, String email, String password) {

try{
UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
}catch(e){
print(e);
}

Future <void> signOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

}
```

**LoginPage.dart**

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() async{
        if (_loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        _loginFormKey.currentState!.save();
        await AuthService.login(context, email!, password!);
        }
      });
    },
    style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor:
            MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                (states) => Colours.blk),
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ))),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          "Log in"
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

**Home.dart**

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
  Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false)
                                .signOut();
  });
  },
  icon: const Icon(
  IC.MaterialIcons.logout,
  )),
```

Whenever i use sign out after successfully signing in, the current user id is persistent which makes it impossible to sign in with different credentials unless you restart the website

Comment: At a first glance, you're not calling `signOut` anywhere in the code you shared.

Comment: I am, i just didn't include it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try sign out like this

```dart
Future<void> _signOut() async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work as well. @Kaushik

Comment: When the user logs out set the current user to null too

Comment: This makes the current user id equal to null throughout the website.

Comment: Once you set the user to null navigate to the login page by push and remove until